# Why EF does not allow conversion on Query generation period?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

### EF( Entity FrameWork) codes look

**My Error:**

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

**My Code**

```
 public List<AttendanceDisplayModel> GetAttendanceById(string userId)
        {
            TimeSpan StartTime = TimeSpan.Parse("9:00:00");
            TimeSpan EndTime = TimeSpan.Parse("18:00:00");
            return travelContext.Attendances.Where(a => a.UserId == userId).Select(s => new AttendanceDisplayModel()
                  {
                      Id = s.Id,
                      EmployeeNumber = s.EmployeeNumber,
                      Absent = s.Absent,
                      AttendanceDate = s.AttendanceDate,
                      BelowTime = s.BelowTime,
                      CompanyId = s.CompanyId,
                      CompOffId = s.CompanyId,

                      HoliDayId = s.HoliDayId,
                      InTime = s.InTime,
                      OutTime = s.OutTime,
                      ISCompOFF = s.ISCompOFF,
                      Late = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(StartTime, s.InTime))).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"),
                      Early = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(s.InTime, StartTime))).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"),
                      LeaveId = s.LeaveId,
                      OverTime = s.OverTime,
                      UserId = s.UserId,
                      WeekOff = s.WeekOff,
                      WorkHour = s.WorkHour
                  }).ToList();
        }
```

**Error Comes From this line**

```
Late = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(StartTime, s.InTime))).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"),
                      Early = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(s.InTime, StartTime))).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"),
```

avvv!! Actually am big angry with the Cute EF(Entity Framework). Because I can't Convert any objects from inside of EF query, Like my code.

I saw Soooo many solutions from stackoverflow. The solution only **can declare the variables in globally, then you can use it on the `EF` Query.** But  i can't declare any global calculations variable for in this situation. This Why am called `EF` is `WTF` code..

Please any one tell to `Entity Framework`, for accept conversion into code generation period.

> And give me the solution for this kind of situation. I need to calculate different mins and convert it it hour and mins and sec(00:00:00) formate.

Thanks

Comment: `ToString` in this case may be simple to you but to EntityFramework, it is just a custom method (like a black box), it cannot know exactly what inside to convert the whole into an Expression. In earlier versions of EF, you cannot even call as many methods (in query) as in the current version. In some cases we have to manually build up the Expression tree ourselves but it's fairly complicated and you should consider if it's worth that.

Answer (score 1):

EF cannot convert the ToString(format) to an SQL expression, the best you can do is to retrieve from the database the timespan and then add a non-maped property which returns the timespan as an string, something like this:

```
public class AttendanceDisplayModel
{
    //blablabla 
    public TimeSpan Late { get; set; }
    public string LateFormatted{ get{ return Late.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); } }
}
```

EDIT: Modification to do all the work on those properties:

```
public class AttendanceDisplayModel
{
    //blablabla 
    public int Late { get; set; }
    public string LateFormatted{ get{ return new TimeSpan((double)Late ).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); } }
}
```

and in your query isntead of:

```
 Late = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(StartTime, s.InTime))).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"),
```

do

```
 Late = EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(StartTime, s.InTime),
```

**EDIT**:

And now the full code:

```
public class AttendanceDisplayModel
{
    //The rest of the propertis as you have them
    public int Late { get; set; }
    public string LateFormatted{ get{ return new TimeSpan((double)Late).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); } }
    public int Early{ get; set; }
    public string EarlyFormatted{ get{ return new TimeSpan((double)Early).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); } }
}

    public List<AttendanceDisplayModel> GetAttendanceById(string userId)
    {
        TimeSpan StartTime = TimeSpan.Parse("9:00:00");
        TimeSpan EndTime = TimeSpan.Parse("18:00:00");
        return travelContext.Attendances.Where(a => a.UserId == userId).Select(s => new AttendanceDisplayModel()
              {
                  Id = s.Id,
                  EmployeeNumber = s.EmployeeNumber,
                  Absent = s.Absent,
                  AttendanceDate = s.AttendanceDate,
                  BelowTime = s.BelowTime,
                  CompanyId = s.CompanyId,
                  CompOffId = s.CompanyId,

                  HoliDayId = s.HoliDayId,
                  InTime = s.InTime,
                  OutTime = s.OutTime,
                  ISCompOFF = s.ISCompOFF,
                  Late = EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(StartTime, s.InTime),
                  Early = EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(s.InTime, StartTime),
                  LeaveId = s.LeaveId,
                  OverTime = s.OverTime,
                  UserId = s.UserId,
                  WeekOff = s.WeekOff,
                  WorkHour = s.WorkHour
              }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I  know, i can't. I need answer for Why am can't? i did't get any build error. ..aaa. 

also i can't convert it to Double.. Why ?

Comment: Because SQL does not have those built in functions, letme moduify my answer

Comment: `Formatted` means? any class or something else? but you have gave such a key for me +1

Comment: F*ck*ng spaces.. just remove them, I meant lateFormatted

Comment: can you repost how looks now your query?

Comment: Same as your code. I have implement your code only. does not build error. But it's threw run time error `This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities`

Comment: hmmm, that's not the same error, what are you using? linq to sql, linq to entities or linq to objects?

Comment: Then you wrote something out of place, let me rewrite my answer with the full code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88253/discussion-between-ramesh-rajendran-and-gusman).

Answer (score 1):

Without digging into the types I can't suggest a better solution than this but materializing the query with ToList() before doing the translation with Select() should do the trick. It removes the EF Linq Provider from the equation.

```
return travelContext.Attendances.Where(a => a.UserId == userId).ToList().Select(s => new AttendanceDisplayModel()
              {
                  Id = s.Id,
                  EmployeeNumber = s.EmployeeNumber,
                  Absent = s.Absent,
                  AttendanceDate = s.AttendanceDate,
                  BelowTime = s.BelowTime,
                  CompanyId = s.CompanyId,
                  CompOffId = s.CompanyId,

                  HoliDayId = s.HoliDayId,
                  InTime = s.InTime,
                  OutTime = s.OutTime,
                  ISCompOFF = s.ISCompOFF,
                  Late = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(StartTime - s.InTime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"),
                  Early = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(s.InTime - StartTime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"),
                  LeaveId = s.LeaveId,
                  OverTime = s.OverTime,
                  UserId = s.UserId,
                  WeekOff = s.WeekOff,
                  WorkHour = s.WorkHour
              });
```

Convertion not checked. I leave it to you to sort that out.

Comment: I got a error man `This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.` :( sad

Comment: Oh. Yeah I see now you are using EntityFunctions. Those only work with entity framework linq provider. You would be doing the conversion without that now. Will edit..

Comment: ` TimeSpan.FromMinutes()` only neds double values, does not timespan values .. error :(

Comment: I don't know the types of your class ie. s.InTime but use the compiler or documentation and fix it. This is just c# code now without the EF error. I am sure you can work it out.

Answer (score 0):

EF does not know how to convert any custom method, regardless of who's framework it's in, into SQL unless it specifically knows how to do it. 
The connection could be backed by various different database types so there isn't support for this kind of thing even if you logically know it could be converted to SQL. 
Use EF to retrieve the data and then after calling a ToList or similar on it you will then be able to call LINQ and custom methods on it once now that the data has been materialised into actual data. 
This catches me out occasionally, but can be handled through executing lambda, methods or properties on the retrieved data to perform your operations.